# Redirecionamento de página jsp usando SpringFramework

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Olá!

Estou com seguinte problema em fazer um redirecionamento da página index.jsp para página de login.jsp, no tomcat só aparece que essa página não foi encontrada, ERRO 404. Se alguém puder ajudar, estou usando  e estudando Spring, talvez tenha algo diferente das páginas jsf.

**Index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Aguarde...</h1>    
    <c:redirect url="login/login.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Tela de Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Testando....</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gervasios.sgr" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="true" version="3.0">
    <display-name>sgr-application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Usando o spring eu tenho que usar somente páginas jsp ?

Comment: Você já tentou fazer  `<c:redirect url="./login.jsp"/>` ou `<c:redirect url="login/login.xhtml"/>`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta MiguelCPJava, respondi minha pergunta com a solução.

Answer (score 1):

Tive que apagar todo código jsp da minha página de index e deixar somente esse trecho.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:redirect url="/login"/>
```